# How to Generate Key and Chiper initiation below Android API 23?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

Am Using Fingerprint Authentication for App. Want to Support for below API 23 also. For that am Using **FingerprintManagerCompat**. I don't know how to **Generate Key** and **Chiper initiation** in Pre-Android API 23.

**Below Code am Used for API 23 - Generate Key**

```
protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**Below Code am Used for API 23 - Chiper initiation**

```
public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
            | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
```

I don't know how initiate these two things in Pre API 23 to access **FingerprintManagerCompat**, Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

FingerprintManager is not available in pre-marshmallow devices. They have added this API in Marshamallow which is specified [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html)

Comment: Fingerprint sensor available in Some mobiles with API 21.

Answer (score 1):

No.You can't Generate Key and cipher below API 23(Marshmallow 6.0).

> Some android device have fingerprint sensor below API 21 but android only supports for API 23 and above.You have to use their sdk for fingerprint authentication.Samsung provide their own sdk for fingerprint authentication i.e Pass Sdk.

You can see this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html).Sample project for Finger Print Authentication [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html)